# PHP sequential foreach

Tags: php, foreach, sequential

Guys i've got an array thats like this:

```
  array(3) {
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(13) "row1"
        [1]=>
        string(13) "row3"
      }
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(15) "row1"
        [1]=>
        string(15) "row3"
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(13) "row1"
        [1]=>
        string(13) "row3"
      }
    }
```

What i want to achieve is make foreach loop the 0 elements (row1) and then loop through 1 (row3) and go on like this. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This looks like the result of a query. Why not make your query return the correct format?

Comment: Its not a query, its a browser input and i can't force the users to order the elements correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to rebuild the array:

```
$rows = array();
foreach($array as $subarray) 
  foreach($subarray as $key => $value)  
    $rows[$key][] = $value;
```

At this point al the same subelements from the array are together in a new array, and now you can easy loop over a subelement:

```
  foreach($rows as $key => $value)  
    echo 'processing row: ' . $key ' with value ' . $value;
```

Comment: The problem is that this is dynamic array, it may contain more than 2 fields, so 0/1 won't cut it.

Comment: You did not mention that in your question.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to you new needs

Comment: Thank you for this one, i did forgot to include this detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach to this problem, the JvdBeg solution is working wonderful, but if someone is stuck in a similar situations, this is how i did it:
        $key  = key($arr);
        $keys = array_keys($arr);

```
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr[$key]['index']);$i++) {
      for($k=0;$k<sizeof($arr);$k++) {
        $key = $keys[$k];
        echo "\n";
      }
    }
```